# I would like to include apostrophe in the output attributes

Tags: xslt, xpath, xsd, xslt-2.0, workday-api

I wrote a code to eradicate all the special characters with a function.

```
<xsl:function name="lancet:stripSpecialChars">
<xsl:param name="string" />
<xsl:variable name="AllowedSymbols" 
select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'"/>
<xsl:value-of select="
translate(
$string,
translate($string, $AllowedSymbols, ' '),
' ')
"/>
</xsl:function> 

<xsd:element xtt:fixedLength="14" xtt:required="true" xtt:severity="error" xtt:align="left">
            <xsl:value-of select="lancet:stripSpecialChars(upper-case(replace(normalize-unicode(translate($emp/wd:First_Name, ',', ' '), 'NFKD'), '⁄', '/')))"/>
        </xsd:element>
```

Now there is a requirement for me to include apostrophe ('). When I am trying to include the same in AllowedSymbols, I am getting an error.

The output Right now is **D AGOSTINO**. I need something like **D'AGOSTINO**.

Not sure how to handle this. Could someone please help me out with this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say what the error is, but you probably just need to escape the apostrophe in your variable.

This is done by doubling up the apostrophe:

```
<xsl:variable name="AllowedSymbols" select="'''ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'"/>
```

Since you're using XSLT 2.0, you should be able to use `replace()` instead of `translate()`...

```
<xsl:function name="lancet:stripSpecialChars">
  <xsl:param name="string"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="replace($string,'[^A-Z0-9'']','')"/>
</xsl:function>
```

I'm not replacing lowercase letters since the string you're passing is already forced to uppercase, but if you use the function elsewhere you can add `a-z` to the character class.

Answer (score 0):

- Encode it as `&apos;` (`&#8217;` also)
- Enclose the value in a CDATA section (recommended as you get rid of encoding problems.

`<data><![CDATA[some stuff including D'Agostino & other reserved/problematic characters :-) ]]></data>`